# OSX development, Xib menu and how the storyboard Window Controller associated?

Tags: swift, macos

I have two UI files, MainMenu.xib and Main.storyboard, the Main Interface of the project is MainMenu.xib, this file is only NSView, no other WindowView.

I don't know how to relate them. I want to implement the click MainMenu.xib menu to open Window Controller in Main.storyboard. But I don't know how to do it.

If they're in a storyboard, they should be pretty good, but now they're apart. I don't know what to do with it.

Please help me find some demo or documentation to make this clearer for me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

While some macOS apps mix XIB files and storyboards (especially apps that have custom table view cells), most apps in general will either be XIB files or they will be storyboard based.

You need to decide which approach you want to take for your app. Storyboards are great if your app is developed by one or two developers and you won't be merging or colliding changes with each other often.  XIB files are more appropriate for larger teams as each XIB file typically contains a single window controller plus a view (and maybe a view controller, too), so there's less chance of havoc when doing merges back into GitHub or your Subversion repo.

Look at your target setting's "Deployment Info" section.  For me, it looks like this:

[image: Deployment Info]

When you make your decision for XIB or Storyboard, you can make sure of the one you want to use via that field.

Comment: The main thing I want to know is how my menu displays the Window Controller in another Storyboard

Comment: If this were my problem, I'd take the contents of your Window Controller (which live in your "`Main.xib`", right?) and move them into the Main.storyboard file (making sure to re-wire up all the outlets & actions).